# Is the seed stored inside the database associated with the core?

Tags: stellar-core

For security reasons, I'd like to know whether the seed is stored in the database. Obviously, its configured in the core's config file, but does the app copy it into the database? I suspect it does not, but I'd like to see this confirmed.